# Existence of a functional inequality

Tags: inequality, functional-inequalities

Does there exist $f=f(x)$ satisfying $f(x)\ge0$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=f(-x)$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $f$ is even), $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x)\,dx<\infty$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} x^2\,f(x)\,dx<\infty$ such that for some $C>0$ (independent of $a$ and $b$), we have

\begin{equation}
a\,f\Big(\frac{x}{a}\Big)-b\,f\Big(\frac{x}{b}\Big)\ge C\,(a-b)\,f\Big(\frac{x}{a-b}\Big)
\end{equation}
for all $a>b>0$ and $x\in\mathbb{R}$. My idea is to use the Jesen inequality to show that the above inequality holds for some class of $f$. However, I failed to do so. Is it possible to find an example of such $f$? Any comment, idea, or suggestion is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: It holds trivially for the zero function, $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Doesn't really help though...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Surely I need a nontrivial answer:)

Comment: I think it holds for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$ and $C=1$. Haven't verified that however, just a gut feeling.

Comment: Nobody's function is log-concave, so maybe you might get something there...

Comment: I use Mathematica to plot for some $a$ and $b$ when $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$, and it shows that the desired inequality holds for these $a$ and $b$. So the next step is to show this inequality holds for $f(x)=e^{-x^2}$. Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: I've got nothing. Maybe you could get something out of considering the zeros of such a $f$? For such a function $f$, you must have $af(\frac{x_0}{a})-bf(\frac{x_0}{b})=0\iff f(\frac{x_0}{a-b})=0$ and $a-b=c>0$ can be written as the difference of two positive real terms in uncountably many ways.

If $x_1\ne x_0$, then $x_1/\gamma=x_0/(a-b)$ up to a sign for some $\gamma>0$ so if $\gamma=r_1-r_2$, $r_1>r_2>0$ then $r_1f(\frac{x_1}{r_1})-r_2f(\frac{x_1}{r_2})=0$. In other words, given one zero, for any $x$, you can find $r_1>r_2>0$ such that $r_1f(\frac{x_1}{r_1})-r_2f(\frac{x_1}{r_2})=0$.

Comment: @LCH Call $g(x)=\frac{af(x/a)-bf(x/b)}{(a-b)f(x/(a-b))}$ and show that $g'(x)=0$ has a real solution only at $x=0$. Demonstrate $g$ is convex. Conclude $g(0)=1$ is a global minimum.

Comment: @ Nobody Thanks! I'm trying to follow your idea to prove the desired result.

Comment: @LCH Don't haha I just checked this myself and it's not necessarily true that $g$ is convex. Whoops!

Comment: @ Nobody Now I've an idea. Perhaps it helps to find the critical points of $G(x):=a\,f(\frac{x}{a})-b\,f(\frac{x}{b})-(a-b)\,f(\frac{x}{a-b})$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example: $$f(x)=\begin{cases}1, |x|\le 1\\0, |x|>1\end{cases}$$
The integrals are finite. Since $a>b>0$, you get $a>a-b>0$. There are two cases, $b\ge a-b$ and $b<a-b$.

If $|x|>a$, $f(x/a)=f(x/b)=f(x/(a-b))=0$, so your condition is verified for any $C$. If $|x|<b$ and $|x|<a-b$, then $f(x/a)=f(x/b)=f(x/(a-b))=1$, and your condition is verified for any $C<1$. What you are left with is $|x|\le a$ and

(a)$|x|>b, |x|>a-b$,

(b)$|x|>b, |x|<a-b$,

(c)$|x|<b, |x|>a-b$.

For (a) you get $a-b\cdot 0\ge C(a-b)\cdot 0$, which is always true. For (b) you have $a-b\cdot 0\ge C(a-b)$ which once again is true if $C<1$. For (c) you get $a-b\ge C(a-b)\cdot 0$, true for any C